# Ergonomic PC keyboard/mouse/stand solution for multi-OS MacBookPro with Home/End/PageUp/PageDn/Insert/Delete keys

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro

I am stuck with MacBookPro as my main working laptop in the foreseeable future, and I run OS/X and also Windows and Linux on it at the same time, frequently switching between them. While this computer generally works well otherwise, I hate Apple keyboard. After years of working on PC keyboards, I've spent few months trying to get used to MBP keyboard, but still can't.

My major gripe is the absence of *Home*, *End*, *Page-Up*, *Page-Down*, *Insert/Delete* keys. I know there are multi-key combinations which emulate those on Mac, but they just don't do it for me. At this point, I gave up and I'm looking for hardware solution that involves external keyboard and that's what I need help with. When I attach regular external keyboard, that requires to push the screen too far from the eyes.

So far, I narrowed it down to the following two possible setups (for 15-inch MBP):

1. External PC keyboard (preferably wireless) which stands **directly over** MacBookPro keyboard without touching its keys. It must be elevated by at least 15mm at each point and its legs must be 17 inches apart. I haven't found any such thing so far. Many keyboards come with retractable legs, but their dimensions is not something that is published in the specs.
2. Some sort of dock/stand which fits 15'' MacBookPro specifically and holds it at an angle bringing the screen closer to my face, preferably with built-in PC keyboard. Something like this 2Cool Stand: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834965024, but with full PC keyboard having Home/End/PgUp/PgDown keys (which this product lacks as far as I can tell).

I am looking for other possible solutions or hardware recommendations.

Comment: Don't this falls under Product Recommendation and basically Off Topic for this site?

Answer (score 1):

How about a Rain Stand?

http://www.raindesigninc.com/mstand.html

You should be able to get it close to you, you can choose a full size keyboard of your choice. I'm a fan of the Kinesis: http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/advantage-lf-for-pc-mac/

But even the official Apple full size keyboard is pretty nice.